# Kentico 9 static IP configuration issue

Tags: asp.net, kentico

I am facing a strange problem. I am using Kentico 9 CMS edition.

I have the Kentico CMS website in my Windows 10 PC in C:\inetpub\. I have configured this path in IIS to be the default Document Root path. I have now mapped this PC's IP address to a static IP which I have been alloted. Now I have a sub-domain (sub.domainname.com) mapped to this static IP, which in turn, is mapped to my local IP. So when I try to access the portal using the sub-domain, it goes to a 404 page. However, I am able to login to Admin using the sub.domainname.com/cuff5863912 URL. But my front-end keeps giving me the 404 error page.

**Configurations I did in CMS:**

1) I went to Sites > Domains and entered the Static IP as one entry and also another entry for the sub-domain (sub.domainname.com)

2) I went to Domain Aliases and entered 2 entries for Static IP and sub-domain.

3) I went to Settings > Content Managment > and set the  Default Website URL to '/Home'

4) I went to Licenses and added 2 FREE Kentico 9.x licenses, one for Static IP and one for sub-domain (both created from Kentico Client portal)

5) I went to IIS (ver 8) control panel and created a Binding of 443 port and entered the host name as the sub-domain (sub.domainname.com)

6) We had tried running the portal in https://localhost and that was working fine. But since the time put this new Static IP and Sub-domain (mapped to the static IP), its not working at all. Sometimes it gives System Error and keeps redirecting to some loginURL endlessly or 404 error.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

at sites application edit your site and at the domain text box enter
 sub.domainname.com only

any oher domains or IP addresses should be added to domain aliases